# When you change the default language to any other language, the jspui displays error in home page

Tags: user-experience, dspace

added in **webui.supported.locales = en, es, ru, pt** but works only the default language (English):

when I change the language in dspace it returns me this error on the home page of JSPUI:

works only the default language (English):

[image]

with spanish:

[image]

what was configured wrong or is missing a some file?

```
 -- Method: GET
 -- Parameters were:
 -- locale: "es"
```

---

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file news-top_es.html is not a valid news file
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file news-top_es.html is not a valid news file
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.util.JSPManager.showJSP(JSPManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file news-top_es.html is not a valid news file
    at org.dspace.core.NewsManager.readNewsFile(NewsManager.java:47)
    at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:173)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    ... 44 more
2016-06-17 10:09:14,289 INFO  org.dspace.browse.BrowseEngine @ anonymous:session_id=89F8495EC293DE76D6769E0123498CC9:ip_addr=172.19.30.197:browse_mini:
2016-06-17 10:09:14,293 INFO  org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.DiscoverUtility @ facets for scope, null: 2
2016-06-17 10:09:14,303 WARN  org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.InternalErrorServlet @ :session_id=89F8495EC293DE76D6769E0123498CC9:internal_error:-- URL Was: http://172.19.30.197:8080/jspui/internal-error?locale=pt_BR
-- Method: GET
-- Parameters were:
-- locale: "pt_BR"

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file noticias-topo.html is not a valid news file
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file noticias-topo.html is not a valid news file
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.util.JSPManager.showJSP(JSPManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file noticias-topo.html is not a valid news file
    at org.dspace.core.NewsManager.readNewsFile(NewsManager.java:47)
    at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:173)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    ... 44 more
2016-06-17 10:09:16,380 INFO  org.dspace.browse.BrowseEngine @ anonymous:session_id=89F8495EC293DE76D6769E0123498CC9:ip_addr=172.19.30.197:browse_mini:
2016-06-17 10:09:16,386 INFO  org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.DiscoverUtility @ facets for scope, null: 2
2016-06-17 10:09:17,946 INFO  org.dspace.browse.BrowseEngine @ anonymous:session_id=89F8495EC293DE76D6769E0123498CC9:ip_addr=172.19.30.197:browse_mini:
2016-06-17 10:09:17,950 INFO  org.dspace.app.webui.discovery.DiscoverUtility @ facets for scope, null: 2
2016-06-17 10:09:17,961 WARN  org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.InternalErrorServlet @ :session_id=89F8495EC293DE76D6769E0123498CC9:internal_error:-- URL Was: http://172.19.30.197:8080/jspui/internal-error?locale=ru
-- Method: GET
-- Parameters were:
-- locale: "ru"

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file news-top_ru.html is not a valid news file
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file news-top_ru.html is not a valid news file
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.dspace.app.webui.util.JSPManager.showJSP(JSPManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file news-top_ru.html is not a valid news file
    at org.dspace.core.NewsManager.readNewsFile(NewsManager.java:47)
    at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:173)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The DSpace translates the documents "news-top and news-side" to all Supported languages, for default accepts only "news-top and news-side", it's necessary put the translation of name "top-news and news-site" for the dspace accept.

Add in

> dspace\config\spring\api\core-services.xml

in example to pt_BR:

```
  <list>

                <value>news-top.html</value>
                <value>noticias-topo.html</value>

                <value>news-side.html</value>
                <value>noticias-lado.html</value>

            </list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I was having the same problem. Then i followed the Brendow's tip, but this doesnt work out.

So i solved my problem this way:

Add in:

> dspace\config\spring\api\core-services.xml

```
<list>
            
    <value>news-top.html</value>
    <value>news-side.html</value>
    
    <value>news-top_pt.html</value>
    <value>news-side_pt.html</value>
        
</list>
```

I didn't put the literal translation of the news, I just added the acronym of the language. Despite that Brendow's tip was useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Default locale is meant to be unique, I think. You'd better add the list of supported languages in `webui.supported.locales`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the comments to find a quick fix for Dspace 5.5

https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-3107

AND: as Benoît Wéry wrote:

" Default locale is meant to be unique, I think. You'd better add the list of supported languages in webui.supported.locales. "